# Retrieving Database procedure value with Provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, t-sql

I am trying to retrieve data from my database procedure but I'm not sure why I'm getting a return value of -1 when a value of 1 or 0 is supposed to be returned. I feel as thought everything is being passed in correctly and the procedure is running well. But I could be wrong.

I pass an object with the name of "Status" of type int into my database procedure db.proc_CsStatus and db.proc_GhStatus. During the debugger though I get "r" a value of -1.

My Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.CsStatus = GhCsStatusProvider.GetCsStatus();
        ViewBag.GhStatus = GhCsStatusProvider.GetGhStatus();
        return View();
    }
```

My provider has these two functions:

```
             public static int GetGhStatus()
             {
                 using (Entities db = new Entities())
                 {
                     System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter s = new System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter("Status", typeof(int));
                     int r = db.proc_CsStatus(120, s);
                     return r;
                 }
             }

             public static int GetCsStatus() 
             {
                 using (Entities db = new Entities())
                 {
                     System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter s = new System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter("Status", typeof(int));
                     int r = db.proc_CsStatus(120, s);
                     return r;
                  }
             }
```

Here are my database procedures:

### For proc_GhStatus

```
    USE [DATABASE_GH]
    GO

    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO

    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_GhStatus]
        -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
        @TimeLimit Int,
        @Status Int OUTPUT
    AS
    BEGIN
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON

        -- Declare variables.
        DECLARE @LastUpdate Int

        -- Calculate the LastUpdate.
        SELECT @LastUpdate = DATEDIFF(second, Timestamp, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
        FROM Heartbeat
        WHERE Id=2

        -- Compare it to the TimeLimit.
        IF @LastUpdate > @TimeLimit SELECT @Status = 0
        ELSE SELECT @Status = 1
    END

    GO
```

### For CsStatus

```
    USE [DATABASE_CS]
    GO


    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO

    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO


    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_CsStatus]
        -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
        @TimeLimit Int,
        @Status Int OUTPUT
    AS
    BEGIN
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON

        -- Declare variables.
        DECLARE @LastUpdate Int

        -- Calculate the LastUpdate.
        SELECT @LastUpdate = DATEDIFF(second, Timestamp, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
        FROM Heartbeat
        WHERE Id=1

        -- Compare it to the TimeLimit.
        IF @LastUpdate > @TimeLimit SELECT @Status = 0
        ELSE SELECT @Status = 1
    END

    GO
```

Comment: You didn't mention what version of EF are you working with and whether DB first or Code first. I assume DB first and EF 4.

You can go to the definition of the roc_CsStatus in the generated 'db' context file. If you see the generated code calls the ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction to execute your SP, then notice that the documentation says all the return values of the SP are discarded and the method actually returns the number of affected rows.

Comment: EF 5. And yes DB first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the stored procedure you are not return the status. Therefore you can't set the status in the code like below.

```
int r = db.proc_CsStatus(120, s);
```

This will only return the status of the stored procedure execution. -1 means there were some errors in stored procedure execution. Simplest way would be remove the out parameter and return the @status from sp. Then you should be able to retrieve the values the way you have done.

```
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    -- Declare variables.
    DECLARE @LastUpdate Int

    -- Calculate the LastUpdate.
    SELECT @LastUpdate = DATEDIFF(second, Timestamp, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    FROM Heartbeat
    WHERE Id=1

    -- Compare it to the TimeLimit.
    IF @LastUpdate > @TimeLimit SELECT @Status = 0
    ELSE SELECT @Status = 1

// Below line shoud be added.

RETURN @Status
```

Also make sure to set right return type in the DBModel as mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 1):

The possible problem is that the imported SP in EF is not told to return a value. To check do the followings:

1. Open the .edmx file.
2. Open Model Browser.
3. Brows to DBModel.
4. Under Function Imports section find your SP and right click on it then open Properties.
5. Check whether the Return Type is set to None or not.
6. If it is not change it to appropriate value.

Comment: cannot find my sp =[. I think it is because the tables are in my edmx but not my procedures

Comment: If the code you posted is correct and working then it shows you call SP via an instance of "Entities" context. So you just go to definition of "proc_CsStatus" to make sure where this SP is defined. To navigate to the definition highlight the "proc_CsStatus" and press F12 or right click, then click "Goto Definition".